# How to run a command from specific directory in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to run a command (say dir) from a specific folder. I tried following but it didn't work.

```
cd C:\Users\administrator\temp; dir;
```

I want to check all the directories present inside `temp` folder. How can I write a Windows batch script for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using "&"

- Any number of commands can be executed separated with &

Example:

```
cd C:\Users\username & dir & cd C:\logs & dir
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the semi-colon's. Just put each command on a new line.

```
cd C:\Users\administrator\temp
dir
```

The above works just fine for me.

Note, you can also use "pushd" and "popd" to change the current directory, perform some work and then return to where you were.

Answer (score -1):

If you want run command window from a specific folder.

Click your folder then **hold** your shift key, then right click you will found option **open command window here** then click it.

Comment: I want to write a batch file for that. Human intervention won't help.